# postgres query only the tables without datetime column

Tags: postgresql

fellow coders :) Im having a trouble querying list of tables without datatype column. 
I did this query

```
select *
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'sampleschema1' or table_schema = sampleschema1'
and columns.data_type != 'timestamp without time zone' and 
columns.data_type != 'date'
```

The above query still return tables that have a column of date datatype. Any help or tips are greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: The construct to use in such a case is `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. That way you can exclude tables that have such a column. Another approach is to use `EXCEPT` between one query on the list of tables and one on the list of tables that have a column like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @LaurenzAlbe appreciated it.